# How much data is a lot for ajax php mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

I am creating a system that will track some information about the web page the users that will come to my web page, basically I am using Java Script Ajax to call PHP functions that will store/ update information in my mysql database (phpmyadmin) using Xampp.
Among those function I am sending every

1. "x" seconds the info if the user is my web page or not.  Basically I update the "page" the user is and the "time" in the page until now, that would be like the previous time plus "x" seconds.
2. "y" seconds I use heat map to get the position of the mouse using ev.pageX and ev.pageY. Once again I update that in the database.
3. Every time the user clicks a button I also store that In my database.

I am currently using "x" = 5 seconds, and "y" = 0.1 seconds I allow the function that will get the points to send to the database or not, the the function is *body.onmousemove = function (ev)*.

I would like to know if I will have problems with my website such as low speed. And also I would like to know if my mysql phpmyadmin xampp will be able to handle lets say 100 users online at the same time sending data to the database.
If I have any complications with that method, what should I do to improve the code and the strategy to store the data?

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Something I forgot to mention, the size that is counting right now is basically of 902 B for the checking if user is in page or not and 225 B for the heat map one.

Comment: It depends on the server if it can handle tons of requests. First, you can try to use Developer tools in Chrome (FF?). For example in Chrome press F12, go to Network tab, use dropdown with `Online` and switch it so `Slow 3G`. And test how your tracks will live on slow connection.

Comment: You might also want to look into the [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) which this really seems like a good fit for. Nothing server-side would change, but you might get slightly better results for calls that would normally drop off when the page is unloaded.

Comment: Also, for performance, you might want to consider logging the data to a store like redis/memcache or just a database even, and then process it later. This will allow you to better control your more processor-intensive logic and clients shouldn't feel the server's burden.

Comment: `"y" = 0.1 seconds` - you mean you send ajax every 0.1 seconds? Or you store the pointer every 0.1 seconds client side and send it in a batch every 5 seconds?

Comment: Means I am using the function: `setInterval(function(){ funcion_that_will_get_the_position_of_the_mouse_if_hover_and_send_by_ajax();},100);`